# Angular.js: angular-ui/ui-router - not work Appended Routes

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-ui-router

I did as shown in the documentation https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router#nested-states--views  - here is my code vieschs http://plnkr.co/edit/0DypwIajU7fOPvQGR5fg 
here it works.

But when I use it in my project **template child is not called**. Call always occurs only parent.

**How can I find the problem?**

My question is similar to this:
[angular-ui/ui-router with Steroids](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22157357/angular-ui-ui-router-with-steroids)

Clone this issue github /angular-ui/ui-router/issues/1172

Answer (score 0):

it may be due to the use of construction?

```
ng.element(document)
    .ready(function () {
        var root = ng.element(document.querySelector('#' + name));
        ng.bootstrap(root, [name]);
        console.timeEnd('application loading');
    });
```